# How to set parameters for chart in spagoBI server?

Tags: open-source, reporting, business-intelligence, spagobi

I'm trying with a static chart in spagobi server and now I need to create a dynamic chart.

How can I set a date parameter for a chart in spagobi server?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1- First of all, edit your Dataset to make it dynamic, add a filter (with you date parameter) in you where statement or whatever..

2- Then, you have to create a LOV (list of value), then create an Analytical driver which take his values from the LOV you already create and finally edit you chart document to add a new parameter which will be linked to the just created Analytical driver.

3- The name of your parameter in your Dataset must have the same name as the url in the parameter you define in your chart document.

Hope this steps will help you